# Django CMS Multi-Level Dropdown Menu

Tags: recursion, menu, parent-child, django-cms, tree-structure

Im kinda new to Django CMS and im trying my best to avoid asking, but this one drives me crazy.
I made a Wiki app with a Topic, and Category model. I hooked it to a Site on my CMS and added it to my Menu. Now i would like to be able to show all Top-Level categories, their Child Categories & Topics, and the Child categories of these, and so on, on my menu.

```
Menu/Navigation should look like this:

Wiki
    Category1
        Category1.1
            Topic
        Category1.2
        Topic
    Category2
        Topic
    Category3
        ...

Right now i can only show the Top categories:

Wiki
    Category1
    Category2
    Category3
```

I Already created a menu.py to get a Custom SubMenu on my Wiki (the one you see above):

```
menu.py

class WikiSubMenu(CMSAttachMenu):
    name = _("Wiki Sub-Menu")

    def get_nodes(self, request):
        nodes = []
        categories = Category.objects.filter(parent_id__isnull=True)

        for c in categories:
            node = NavigationNode(
                mark_safe(c.name),
                c.get_absolute_url(),
                c.id,

            )

            nodes.append(node)

        return nodes

menu_pool.register_menu(WikiSubMenu)
```

My Category Model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ''' Category model. '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='children'
    )
    sort = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['sort', 'name']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('topics:categories_category_detail', (), {'slug': self.slug})

    def get_all_children(self):
        return Category.objects.filter(parent=self)
```

Now, is it possible to create a Sub-SubMenu, for all Categories with Childs, and their Childs, and their Childs, and so on?

Thanks for help & sorry for bad english

**-- EDIT : --**

I just found that:

docs.django-cms.org/en/3.0.6/extending_cms/app_integration.html#integration-modifiers

(Removed direct link to add 2 new Links, sorry for that)

I think that is what im looking for, i was kinda blind that i didn't found it. I'll try it out and Post the Answer if it worked out.

**-- EDIT (AGAIN): --**

The modifier didn't worked for me, but i got a whole piece further,
i read the [Docs](https://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.6/extending_cms/api_references.html#menus.base.NavigationNode) again, and found that i can give the NavigationNodes an optional attr dictonary, which i filled with all Categories with parent=c, on that way i had the data i needed, then i found that real nice [bootstrap dropdown menu](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3), that does exacly what i wanted. So my code until now looks like that:

```
menu.py

class TopicsSubMenu(CMSAttachMenu):
    name = _("Wiki Sub-Menu")

    def get_nodes(self, request):
        nodes = []
        categories = Category.objects.filter(parent_id__isnull=True)

        for c in categories:
            node = NavigationNode(
                mark_safe(c.name),
                c.get_absolute_url(),
                c.pk,
                attr=dict(
                    subcategories=Category.objects.filter(parent=c),),
            )

            nodes.append(node)
        return nodes
```

And my Template:

```
menu.html

{% for child in children %}
    <li>
        {% if child.children %}

            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                {{ child.get_menu_title }}
                <span class="caret">
                </span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                {% for child in child.children %}
                    {% if child.attr.subcategories.count %}
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                {% for subcategory in child.attr.subcategories %}
                                <li>
                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="{{ subcategory.get_absolute_url }}">{{ subcategory }}</a>
                                </li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>


                        </li>
                    {% else %}
                    <li><a href="{{child.get_absolute_url}}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</li></a>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}

            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{{ child.get_absolute_url }}">
                <span>
                    {{ child.get_menu_title }}
                </span>
            </a>
        {% endif %}
    </li>

    {% if class and forloop.last and not forloop.parentloop %}
    {% endif %}


{% endfor %}
```

My next step will be to write the whole "for" loops from the template in a Method, make it recursive with a while loop or something and post the result as Answer.

I hope i can help someone with that stuff :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WOHO! I finally did it!

base.html

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        {% show_menu 0 100 100 100 "menu.html" %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

menu.html:

```
{% for child in children %}
    <li class="child{% if child.selected %} selected{% endif %}{% if child.ancestor %} ancestor{% endif %}{% if child.sibling %} sibling{% endif %}{% if child.descendant %} descendant{% endif %}{% if child.children %} dropdown{% endif %}">

        <a {% if child.children %}class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"{% endif %} href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}">
            <span>{{ child.get_menu_title }}</span>{% if child.children|length %}<span class="caret"></span>{% endif %}
        </a>

        {% if child.children %}
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active "dropdownmenu.html" "" "" child %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

    </li>
    {% if class and forloop.last and not forloop.parentloop %}{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

and my dropdownmenu.html:
(The recursive stuff starts here)

```
{% load i18n menu_tags cache mptt_tags %}
{% for child in children %}
    <li {% if child.children %}class="dropdown-submenu"{% else %} {% endif %}>
        <a tabindex="-1" href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a>
        {% if child.children %}
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active "dropdownmenu.html" "" "" child %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

and the most important, menu.py:

```
class TopicsSubMenu(CMSAttachMenu):
    name = _("Wiki Sub-Menu")

    def get_nodes(self, request):
        nodes = []
        categories = Category.objects.all()

        for c in categories:
            node = NavigationNode(
                mark_safe(c.name),
                c.get_absolute_url(),
                c.pk
            )
            if c.parent:
                node.parent_id = c.parent_id
            nodes.append(node)

        topics = Topic.objects.all().exclude(category__isnull=True)
        for t in topics:
            node = NavigationNode(
                mark_safe(t.title),
                t.get_absolute_url(),
                t.pk,
                t.category.all()[0].id,
                parent_namespace="TopicsSubMenu"
            )
            nodes.append(node)
        return nodes

menu_pool.register_menu(TopicsSubMenu)
```

And thats it!