# Drop down menu based on another drop down menu in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Is there a way to use something like dynamic forms in Django? I don't mean something like `django-dynamic-forms 0.5.1` where you can create forms in Admin.

[image]

Simple example:

So on the web page, I could choose, for example, **state** from `drop down menu` and then, right next to this `drop down menu` there would be another `drop down menu` where I could choose city (based on the first `drop down menu`).

The real problem:

In my project, there is a `Translator` which can be able to translate many languages with 3 possible levels ( like Native, Intermediate ... ).

When customer want's to get something translated, they have to fill the `CreationJobForm` - an here is a problem. It is possible that customer wants to translate some text into multiple languages - so he would just choose those languages.

But what if there is just one `Translator` speaking Chineese on Basic level and customer wants professional level - according to this situation, I can't just create a form with `drop down menu` - `Language` and `drop down menu` - `Level`, because the customer could be able to choose `professional` level which is not possible for us to translate.

So my point is that I would like to have a form in which customer could choose language and based on that language, he would be able to choose only those levels which are in our database. Then he could choose another language, then level etc.

Is it possible to make it work through Django forms?

Maybe, this approach would be simpler because you can prepare the form just once and you don't need to change the second drop down menu after filling the first.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if is possible with django-forms but is pretty easy with JavaScript (JQuery).

Comment: I'm not an expert but I think that it could be possible because you know all information before you render the page. I would appreciate any advice how to solve this problem/

Comment: I don't have a clue how it would be done with JQuery since I don't know JS and don't know how to connect JS with Django.

Comment: I think this question is related to yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975708/django-cms-multi-level-dropdown-menu

Comment: other one https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookCategoryDataModelPostMagic

Comment: I think what you need is to take a look at the https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects

Comment: I've seen that before but I'm not sure whether it is good to change my models...

Comment: You would connect jQuery and Django through Ajax, and something like django-rest-framework

Comment: Why don't you think about using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/, to handle translate in your project, as for the widget you want to build, read this http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/master/#, it will help you build custom widget for the application.